# Add React Component to Laravel

Tags: laravel, reactjs, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm new to Laravel and react and I just wanted to use react component along side with Laravel. I followed the process described [here](https://blog.tighten.co/adding-react-components-to-a-laravel-app) but when I run `gulp watch` I get this error:

```
C:\wamp64\www\laravel51\node_modules\laravel-elixir-webpack-react\main.js:3
Elixir.ready(function() {
   ^

TypeError: Elixir.ready is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\laravel51\node_modules\laravel-elixir-webpack-react\main.js:3:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\laravel51\gulpfile.js:23:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

I also run command `npm install --save-dev laravel-elixir-webpack-react` but get same error. 
my `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.10",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-react": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

my gulpfile is:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-webpack-react');
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.webpack('app.js');
});
```

and I work with Laravel 5.1 in windows.

Comment: Show us your gulpfile please.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with 5.1 in quite some time, so I can't help you. Don't get caught up in the LTS stuff if you're just starting, highly recommend to go straight to Laravel 5.4

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy but I have to work with 5.1 because my codes are going to be part of a project which has been written with laravel 5.1